# Three.js slow on phone's vertical screen

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, three.js, webgl

I have this [codepen](https://codepen.io/annamakestuff/pen/RBxbWv) that I made into a [website](https://seasons986.github.io/congratti/). My problem is that it performs really slowly on the Chrome browser on my Nexus 5X phone, but when I rotate the screen to horizontal view or when I view the CodePen it runs smoothly again.

I've tried reversing the width and height to see if it was a screen / window height problem, and I've tried decreasing the height by a lot but it still is the same.

Will someone who is more experienced in webgl or three please explain this to me?

```
function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    height = window.innerHeight;
    width = window.innerWidth;
    aspectRatio = width / height;

  // ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to include some resizing logic in your render loop since the initial window size may change after loading (i.e. when rotated).. and if the window size changes but the renderer is not resized, then the renderer will be rendering to a nonintuitive framebuffer size and may cause problems when trying to scale the output to the actual display.

Edit:

I'm just throwing out guesses. :D And you make good points...

I do see that TODO line 36 Of your index.js.. which could cause problems.. Aside from that everything else in there looks legit to me.

Resizing logic can be tricky, because depending on CSS etc. setting the renderer size, can cause a pathological cascading resize since setting the renderer size, changes the camera size, which can cause a layout change.. and in some strange circumstances can cause small resizes to happen constantly.

Another way to check if this is the problem, is just make your renderer a fixed size square in your init... like 256x256 or something.. and comment out the window.resize listener.. .run that on your phone and see if performance stays consistent on rotations... fwiw, I think i see the issue on my Galaxy S5.. in horizontal mode its super liquid but vertical mode.. seems a little pokey.

Comment: but wouldn't it also be slow if I open up the codepen on my phone then, because the window size hasn't been changed, just loaded?

Comment: Updated my answer a bit.. If you want some realtime help, you can join our informal three help slack channel. I am "thrax" on there.. 
 https://join.slack.com/t/threejs/shared_invite/enQtMzYxMzczODM2OTgxLWE5OTU4OTYxZTZlODk1ZGNjODIyMDZlODM4ZmUyMzNiOWIxMmFjNTYwOTc4MjU0ZmNiODk5MzZiMGJhMTkzZWI

Comment: Thanks! I'll def check it out. For now I did what you said about setting a fixed square and it's running much more smoothly, will just leave it at that for now!

Answer (score 0):

Hey are you using PMREMGenerator at all in the code?
I've noticed that using this to generate environment maps really chuggs on the phones in portrait mode